# NgModel is not working correctly in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a problem like this. I am creating a web application with angular 5, Nodejs and MongoDB. To send data to the database I have created an HTML file like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s5">
            <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
              <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._id">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Enter full name" required>
                  <label>Name :
                    <label class="red-text">*</label>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="position" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.position" placeholder="Eg : Snr. Developer">
                  <label>Position :</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="office" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.office" placeholder="Enter office location">
                  <label>Office :</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="salary" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.salary" placeholder="Salary per annum">
                  <label>Salary :</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <button class="btn btn-custom right" type="button" (click)="resetForm(employeeForm)">Reset</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-custom right" type="submit" [disabled]="!employeeForm.valid">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col s7">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To send data to the backend I have created a method like this in the components.ts file. This the code in that file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';

declare var M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css'],
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.refreshEmployeeList();
  }
  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form) {
      form.reset();
      this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
        _id: '',
        name: '',
        position: '',
        office: '',
        salary: null
      };
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value._id === '') {
      this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        M.toast({ html: 'Saved successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
  }

  refreshEmployeeList() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe( (res) => {
      this.employeeService.employees = res as Employee[];
    });
  }

  onEdit(emp: Employee) {
    this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = emp;
  }

  onDelete(_id: string, form: NgForm) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') === true) {
      this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(_id).subscribe((res) => {
        this.refreshEmployeeList();
        this.resetForm(form);
        M.toast({ html: 'Deleted successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And my service file is like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Employee } from './employee';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  selectedEmployee: Employee;
  public  employees: Employee[];
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, employee);
  }

  getEmployeeList() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }

  putEmployee(emp: Employee) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL + `/${emp._id}`, emp);
  }

  deleteEmployee(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseURL + `/${_id}`);
  }

}
```

My app.module.ts file is like this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my employee model class looks like this.

```
export class Employee {
  public _id: string;
  public name: string;
  public position: string;
  public office: string;
  public salary: number;
}
```

When I hit ng serve it is giving me an error like this.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EmployeeComponent.html:8)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13844)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
```

Yesterday also I asked this question I think my explanation was not clear. So  Today I am asking it with more description. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank You Very much.

Comment: *"Yesterday also i asked this question."* - If you did ask it yeasterday then please don't delete and post again. Instead, just edit what you already posted. People may have responded with context and probably asked for more detail. Once you delete you remove anything relevant that might have already been said. Also the "tags" on your question are for what the "question is about". Don't just tag with everything in you whole stack. The only parts here are "angular", so that is the only tag required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps, but typescript still transpiles to javascript, which really has no way to know that the currentemployee is a class, which is why it says it cannot find the I'd field. However, you can allocate the object which WILL have an I'd field, yet I dont see any place where this is occurring. I think the angular binding is not working because you have only declared, but not initialized the object.

Maybe allocate the employee..

```
public currentEmployee : Employee = new Employee();
```

Please forgive any mistakes, just a general idea to show, typing this at 3am on my android in bed unable to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, though it will generalize your object, it will work:

In your EmployeeService, declare selectedEmployee as below

```
selectedEmployee: any = {};
```